# JS removing object method from this method

Tags: javascript, function

I have this sample code:
https://jsfiddle.net/gdm3rk8r/2/

```
var map = { };
map[5] = function() {
   alert('Hey!');
   delete map[5];
}

map[5]();
```

It's working, but is that correct practise?

Edit1: To be more concrete, I have to exchange or delete a callback from the same callback

Comment: To identify a correct practice, one would need to know the larger use case & then propose a better solution (if there is any). In the current form, it's simply a snippet implemented in the way it's explained & hence correct.

Comment: I would recommend to avoid `delete` for performance reasons in general. You'd rather use `map[5] = null;`

Comment: Use case is simply:
 function(handler){

            var me = this;
            this.handlers[id] = (error) =>{
                if (error) {
                    errorHandler(error);
                    delete me.handlers[id];
                } else {
                    // if no error, set handler
                    me.handlers[id] = handler;
                    okHandler();
                }
            };
}

So, if error happens function calls errorHandler and remove itself from object. In case of error absence function calls okHandler and excahnge itself with handler function for later use

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gdm3rk8r/9/